# Change the colour of radio buttons with selected Wordpress

Tags: html, css, wordpress-theming

Trying to make the radio buttons and checkboxes red when selected?? https://training.thermochamp.com.au/203-2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A radio button is a native elemen to each OS/browser. There is no way to change its default color/style, until unless you want to implement custom images or use a custom Javascript library which includes images

You can try custom radio button or checkbox styling.

https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_custom_checkbox

Comment: Thanks @avilboy2006.
Currently, my quizzes are on learnpress default and I am moving to Watu Quizzes so trying to replicate the look. However the radio buttons are not the same and you cannot just click in the box to select if that makes sense?
This is what I was wanting it to look like - https://training.thermochamp.com.au/wp-content/uploads/sites/3/2020/07/Capture.png

Comment: Don't forget accept answer and upvote if see this helps you. @JustLearning

Comment: what is issue coming ?